# How do I include a csrf token on a post request from a flutter app using dio to a django backend?

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework, dio

I am trying to send a post request to a django backend from a flutter app using dio, how do I get and include the csrf token in the request.
Chatgpt suggested me to use a get request to get the csrf from the backend and include it in the post request.
Is it the correct practice?